# RegEx syntax in tableau for replacing word starting with exact alphabets PR

Tags: syntax, regexp-replace, tableau-desktop

I need help with writing a regex for a column of mixed characters. I want to replace anything starting with PR followed by 4-5 numbers within the string with blank space. help me in writing the syntax for RegEx. this is the current ones I am using in Tableau:

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE([PR Finder 3], '[^PR\d{4,5}]', '')
```

Please help

```
#tableau #regex #RegEx #syntax

REGEXP_REPLACE([PR Finder 3], '[^PR\d{4,5}]', '')
```

used this

Comment: this is basically working except that it is replacing all the capital Ps and Rs in the data

Comment: Try `\bPR\d{4,5}\b` or `^PR\d{4,5}` or `^PR\d{4,5}$` or `^PR\d{4,5}\b`